# Checking XML using Google Maps API

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I have been playing around with Google Maps API for the past couple of days.  I got up to the point where I'm stuck because of my lack of PHP skills.  After running the PHP code below, the XML returned is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<markers/>
```

The link I'm using is: http://www.icliqz.com/Dev/phpsqlsearch_genxml_php.php?latitude=41.782321&longitude=-72.612031&radius=50

The code I'm playing around with is from: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html

I'm using Dreamweaver to work on this project.  If there's a good way to debug through PHP code, I'd really appreciate it.  I tried googling it up, but I'm not sure what is best for a PHP newbie.
I checked that the radius of the records I have in my database.  They are all within 50 miles of the coordinates I'm testing with.

The PHP code is:

```
<?php
require("phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php");

// Start XML file, create parent node
$doc = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $doc->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $doc->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT user, latitude, longitude, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM tbl_UserLatLng HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $doc->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);

  $newnode->set_attribute("user", $row['user']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("latitude", $row['latitude']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("longitude", $row['longitude']);
  $newnode->set_Attribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}

echo $doc->saveXML();

?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your query manually from the mysql shell to see what values are showing up for distance. It seems like you're not getting any results from the db.

```
SELECT user, latitude, longitude, 
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - 
    radians('%s') ) + 
    sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM tbl_UserLatLng
```

Comment: You absolutely right, but I'm not sure why the Having clause is not working.  I'm not sure what is represented by %s.  From what I looked up, it's converting any digits/floats to a string.

Comment: If you want to do string replace like so: $query = sprintf("Select bla bla %s", myvalueToReplace)